# Swift UI with MVVM architecture navigating screens in complicated apps

Tags: ios, mvvm, routes, navigation, swiftui

How can I navigate from one screen to another screen in Swift UI app , I am trying to implement MVVM architecture in my app and I have more than 20 screens so [`NavigationLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) is not suitable in my case .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think you would need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: in UiNavigationController we are pushing ViewControllers , like what I have to do in Swift UI , I need to push Views or ViewModels , and what is the replacement for UINavigationController(navigation stack)

Comment: hmm... and what's wrong with NavigationLink for that purpose?

Comment: It’s exactly what NavigationView and NavigationLink are for.

Answer (score 0):

I quite understand your problem, previously we had a central navigation controller (`UINavigationController`) we could call it anywhere and do a push or pop, but now only the current view can do a navigation using `NavigationLink`, I faced the same problem and the solution was to implement an `UINavigationView` in a sigleton and call it anywhere I want to push a view like `MyNavigation.push(UIHostingController(rootView: NextView()))`.

Anyways, I think this approach is wrong because a new `UIHostingController` is created for every screen, so we lose some of the optimizations introduced by SwiftUI. If you really want to use the powerful features of SwiftUI I recommend you to redesign your app to adapt to SwiftUI capabilities